# How can I write my dataframes to a csv while they are being subset using a for loop

Tags: r

After using a For Loop to subset my data, I would like to automatically write.csv each one of my dataframes. This can happen within my for loop or can be a seperate loop all together, I just do not know how to go about this.

I would like each csv file to be named based on the name of the data frame as well.

```
for (i in FILENAME$COLUMN) {
  nam <- paste("NEW_FILENAME", i, sep = "_")
  assign(nam, FILENAME[
    FILENAME$COLUMN==i,])
}
```

The code I provided subsets the data and create new data frames named 

NEW_FILENAME_1 
NEW_FILENAME_2 
NEW_FILENAME_3 
etc 

The number change is based on the entry used to subset the data.

I need this function because my data set will have hundreds of subsets.

How do I now write a csv for each of these either in the current for loop or using a new for loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to write the files, you can use `tidyverse`  solution. Example, using `mtcars` dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear, carb) %>%
  do(
    write_csv(., sprintf("new_mtcars_g%s_c%s.csv", .$gear[1], .$carb[1]))
  ) %>% 
  invisible()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this with `apply` family instead with the help of `split` which will create list of dataframes for each unique `COLUMN` value you have. So you can create different dataframes as well as write them in different `csv` files in one command only.

For example with `mapply` you could do

```
mapply(function(x, y) 
 write.csv(x, paste0("path_of_file/NEW_FILENAME_", y, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE),
    split(FILENAME, FILENAME$COLUMN), seq_along(unique(FILENAME$COLUMN)))
```

This works with `mtcars` dataset where I create separate dataframe based on `cyl` column

```
mapply(function(x, y) 
   write.csv(x, paste0("NEW_FILENAME_", y, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE), 
      split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl), seq_along(unique(mtcars$cyl)))
```